# C++ function call missing argument list; use '&Runner::runTask' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, c++11

This question seems to have been answered before on SO, but despite looking at other solutions I'm still not able to figure out why I am getting the error:

> function call missing argument list; use '&Runner::runTask' to create a pointer to member

I have a class `Runner` which is going to be responsible for scheduling tasks to run any sub-work on separate threads asynchronously.

In the `start` method of my runner I have the following code:

```
void start(const bool runTaskAsync = true)
{
    if(!isRunning()) return;

    running = true;

    if(runTaskAsync)
    {
        Worker = std::thread(runTask, this);
    } 
    else 
    {
        this->runTask();
    }
}
```

The troublesome line that the compiler doesn't like is: `Worker = std::thread(runTask, this);`.  Based on the error given (and the other questions asked on this site, I attempted to do the following)

```
Worker = std::thread(&Runner::runTask);
```

However I am still getting the same error.   The `runTask` method is a private method on the `Runner` class and is defined as:

```
void runTask()
{
    while(isRunning())
    {
        // this_thread refers to the thread which created the timer
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
        if(isRunning())
        {
            // Function is a public method that we need to call, uses double parens because first calls the function called Function
            // and then the second set of parens calls the function that the calling Function returns
            Function()();
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `Function()()` calls the template function passed to the `Runner` instance, Runners private member variable of `task` is signed as `std::function<void(void)> task;` and the implementation of `Function()()` is signed as:

```
const std::function<void(void)> &Function() const 
{
    return task;
}
```

Which when called (as I understand) will run `Function()` and will then run `task()`

If there are any other details required please let me know.  I am not currently instantiating any instance of `Runner`, I've simply included `Runner.h` in my `main.cpp` file to see whether it would compile.

Comment: brutal, a downvote within 3 seconds of the post going up...I'm sure you can't comprehend the question that quickly..

Comment: Not mine, but that doesn't look like a [MCVE] as required. This is decidable within 3 secs or less.

Comment: Apologies, I'm just trying to keep this as concise as possible without posting the 300+ lines in my header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on the error given (and the other questions asked on this site,
>   I attempted to do the following)
>
> ```
> Worker = std::thread(&Runner::runTask);
> ```

That should be:

```
 Worker = std::thread(&Runner::runTask, this);
```

Every non-static member function takes an implicit `this`, which is exposed (and required) when you want to pass that member function to `std::thread`

Comment: Doh yes this worked - I actually did that earlier but an issue with my disk being full (which I just found the source of) caused a follow up error that I believed was related at the time...now I feel silly...thank you :)

Comment: @Alex, you are welcome. :-) ...It happens. I once thought my PC was infected by a bad virus when every Software were misbehaving in very weird ways, with weird errors, and crashing like crazy. Only for me to find out there was zero bytes left in my HDD

Comment: It's crazy how us software engineers can sometimes over-think the most simple of problems, I guess it serves me right for configuring my VM with only 60GB of memory, looks like I forgot a 0! Whoops :D

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Worker = std::thread(&Runner::runTask, this);
```